# How to use views taxonomy contextual filters with menu tabs?

Tags: views, routes

I have a CT (let's call it Article) with a Status taxonomy field (let's say with values Open, Closed and Cancelled) and I want a **view of Articles with menu tabs for each status** value. And I would like to have it work **with contextual filters on Status** term name.

The **URLs** of the tabs should be like **articles/open**, **articles/closed** etc but the last argument should act also as the contextual filter value. I cannot make it work since drupal takes articles/open as part of the url and I should type articles/open/open to have it use the argument.

Is it possible to be implemented with contextual filters somehow? I would like to **avoid** hidden filter criteria with **taxonomy term value preselected**, as I want to track it with features and I do not want the id of the preselected taxonomy term tracked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the above problem with the following configuration:

I created the *contextual filter* on taxonomy term field and in the filter settings section **When the filter value is NOT in the URL** I selected **Provide default value** and **Raw value from URL** with Path Component 2 and the option Use path alias checked.

In the filter settings section **When the filter value IS in the URL or a default is provided** I selected the appropriate vocabulary and for Filter value type **Term name converted to term ID**.